# Conditional max inside filter kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list, each element with the following fields:
active: true/false,  optional_id: Int?, name: String

I am filtering for fields that have active true, to get the highest optional_id.

```
      testList.filter { it.active == true }
            .maxByOrNull { it.optional_id }
            ?. optional_id ?: 0
```

The idea is, if there are objects in the list, with the field active true, to get the highest optional_id amongst those.
Else, if they are all false (no active field), then return 0.
But since optional_id is of type Int?, maxByOrNull does not accept it without asserting `!!`. Is there any other way to handle null assertions for this scenario ?
I can't change the type of optional_id.

Comment: How do you want to compare nulls with numbers? If a `optional_id` is null, is that considered higher or lower than a non-null value? You want nulls to be considered lower than non-nulls, right?

Comment: Also, if there are active objects, but they all have `optional_id=null`. What do you want the result to be? 0? null?

Comment: If there are active objects, optional_id will always be present, but its definition can't be changed.
Because when they're false, they could have null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`maxOfWithOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-of-with-or-null.html) with a [`nullsFirst`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/nulls-first.html) comparator.

```
val highestOptionalId = testList.filter { it.active == true }
    .maxOfWithOrNull(nullsFirst(naturalOrder())) { it.optionalId }
    ?: 0
```

"Of" suggests that it returns the selector's value, rather than the object in the list. "With" suggests that it uses a `Comparator`.

Comment: Is this actually the most performant solution? calling filter uses an iterator, calling maxOf uses an iterator again, so I suppose using only one iterator/iterating manually would be more performant?

Comment: @David I agree that this is looping twice, and you can always make it a sequence to make it lazy, so that it is iterated only once. Looping one extra time is rarely a performance issue - that one iteration doesn’t usually matter in my experience. Of course, if you profiled and found a performance bottleneck there, then by all means, make it a sequence and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```kotlin
testList.filter { it.active && it.optional_id != null }
    .maxByOrNull { it.optional_id!! } ?.optional_id 
    ?: 0
```

Following `filter(...)` you can safely assume (looks like you have no concurrency concerns) that `optional_id` is not null in `maxByOrNull`.